# Use Glide to load images from URL but without extensions

Tags: java, android, url, android-glide

I could use Glide to load images from my local web server via the following code:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(SERVER_HOST_ADDRESS + userID + ".jpg")
     .into((ImageView) mBinding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.userImage));
```

The problem is that with this method, I am limited to having access only to`.jpg` extensions, when sometimes the user may have chosen to upload a different type of image.
Is there a way for Glide to handle loading an image from a URL, but without the extensions?
Building an iterator would be fine, but may be unnecessary.

Comment: Don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead. Also, don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for Glide to handle loading an image from a URL, but without the extensions?

Yes, though your Web server may not support it.

My interpretation is that you want:

```
.load(SERVER_HOST_ADDRESS + userID)
```

If your Web server serves an image at that URL, with a valid image MIME type, Glide will handle it. Glide itself does not care about file extensions — it wants a valid URL that supplies a valid image MIME type.

However, my guess it that your server will return a 404 error for that URL, because the *server* is expecting the file extension, to match up with the file on the server.

Options to deal with this include:

- Teach the server how to handle the no-extension URL
- Use a consistent image type (e.g., have the server convert everything to JPEG)
- Have some metadata tell you what URL to load (e.g., a Web service call to get details of the user has a JSON property that provides the image URL)
- Do what you suggested and just iterate over the various possibilities and see if one of them works