# Glide won't load placeholder.com image without extension

Tags: android, android-glide

So I use this test endpoint for my sample app https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos

For example Glide tries to load this image `https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355` but fails with

> com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain
> data, status code: 410 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355

```
@BindingAdapter("imageFromUrl")
@JvmStatic
fun loadImageFromUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String?) {
    url?.let { loadImage(imageView, Glide.with(imageView.context).load(it)) }
}

private fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, request: RequestBuilder<Drawable>) {
    request
        //.placeholder(R.drawable.PLACEHOLDER)
        //.error(R.drawable.ERROR)
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
        .into(imageView)
}
```

If I add `".jpg"` to url string (https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355.jpg) then it works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Glide to load images from URL but without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376339/use-glide-to-load-images-from-url-but-without-extensions)

Comment: @AnujSharma well I don't really get it cause I'm not server developer

Answer (score -1):

From [placeholder](https://placeholder.com/) documentation:

> Image format is optional – ***the default is a .GIF.*** You can use the
> following image file extensions… .GIF .JPG .JPEG .PNG

I think you are trying to load a .gif , so you could try this answer: [Show GIF file with Glide (image loading and caching library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-librar)

That's why when you specify a extension it works fine, but that alternative is also valid according to the website.

> Adding an image file extension will render the image in the correct
> format.